# mysql: how to select imploded array value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I have a column that store imploded array values via `,` ,  how can I select array value with the following condition:

if column stored values like below:

```
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
| row |                           column                           |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1   | lorem ipsum,lorem ipsum dolor,lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   |
| --  | --                                                         |
| 2   | consectetuer adipiscing,lorem ipsum amet,lorem ipsum dolor |
| --  | --                                                         |
| 3   | lorem ipsum,consectetuer adipiscing,lorem ipsum dolor      |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to select the rows that has **lorem ipsum** value, I know we can use `Like` but if use `like`, it select **lorem ipsum dolor** or **lorem ipsum amet** too!
I try following  query:

```
select * from table where column like '%lorem ipsum%'

# my expected rows :1,3
# query result :1,2,3
```

Comment: That is going to be a very inefficient query no matter how you write it.

Comment: You know that this is exactly what not to do, right?

Comment: I would say you **might** get away with this **if** you did not want to query based on this column.

Comment: Or better yet, [don't store them like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is comma-separated (and not comma+space separated), you can use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('lorem ipsum', `column`);
```

Comment: In my original query I use join, how to use `FIND_IN_SET` in this case? is `FIND_IN_SET('lorem ipsum',``cast.meta_value``)` true ?

Comment: Yes, `FIND_IN_SET('value', columnname)`, you can add the table/alias name to the column name if necessary.